# Login system C# // Display result problem

Tags: c#

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Login attempt
        int loginAttempts = 0;

        //3 chance login system
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Username");
            string userid = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter password");
            String password = Console.ReadLine();


            if (userid != "Daniel" || password != "polle")
                loginAttempts++;
            else
                break; //Maybe "return"?
        }

        //Show result
        if (loginAttempts > 3)
            Console.WriteLine("Login failure");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Login succesfull");

        Console.ReadLine();




    }
```

I am not getting my display result function to work, when i run the programm it just exits after 3 tries, what can i do differently to get it to display the result? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your `if` condition. You need to have

```
if (loginAttempts >= 3)
```

notice the `>=` instead of `>` sign

Answer (score 0):

*Extract method* and then, yes, `return`:

```
    private static bool TryLogin(int attempts = 3) {
      // Try attempts times
      for (int i = 0; i < attempts; ++i) {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Username");
        string userid = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Enter password");
        string password = Console.ReadLine();

        // if both userid and password are correct return true - login succeed - true
        if (userid == "Daniel" && password == "polle")            
          return true;
      }

      // all attempts are exhausted, login failed - false
      return false; 
    }
```

then use it:

```
    static void Main(string[] args) {
      if (!TryLogin()) {
        Console.WriteLine("Login failure");

        return;
      }

      Console.WriteLine("Login successful"); 

      //TODO: user logged on, put relevant code here 
    }
```